# PyQt4 - Python Image is repeated in toolbar

Tags: python, pyqt, background-image, pyqt4

I am currently working on a small application to do with arranging music lessons and am trying to add a background image. When I add an image it also repeats the image in the menu  bar and toolbar. How can I stop this from happening?

Thanks in advance!

```
    import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class windowMain(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(windowMain, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

#Layout of window
        self.resize(700, 500) #Maximizing main window
        self.center()
        self.setWindowTitle('Lesson Planner') #Setting window title
        self.setStyleSheet("border-image: url(p.jpg);")       
        self.show() #Showing the window
```

Comment: Are you using `qt-designer`? Have you a `resources` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't specify which widget(s) the stylesheet applies to, it will cascade to all child widgets (i.e. just like CSS). So, as with CSS, you need to use the right [selector syntax](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-syntax.html) to apply the background image to the appropriate widget.

For you example, one way to do that would be to set the `objectName` for the central widget of the main window, and then use that name in the selector:

```
    def initUI(self):
        self.centralWidget().setObjectName('CentralWidget')
        self.setStyleSheet("""
            #CentralWidget { background-image: url(./image.png) }
            """)
```